# How Can I call startIntentSenderForResult in Service properly?

Tags: android, android-service, google-play-services

I'm working on a `Service` which gets a location and I'm using Google Play Services for it.

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#hasResolution%28%29, if `hasResolution()` returns `true`, calling `startResolutionForResult` may resolve an error. But it needs an `Activity` as first parameter.

Of course [`ConnectionResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html) returns a `PendingIntent` by `getResolution()` but the `Service` doesn't have a `startIntentSenderForResult()` like an `Activity`.
As far as I know, there is no way to get a result back in a `Service`.

How can I get a result in the `Service`? Or is there another proper way?

**Edit:**

<strike>Google Play Service SDK provides [GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorNotification](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#showErrorNotification%28int,%20android.content.Context%29) for background tasks. Of course accepted answer is good solution.</strike>

**Edit 2:**

`showErrorNotification` is only for a return value of `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would proceed this way:

1. Show a notification indicating that there is a problem doing task X
   (actually, interacting with Google Play Services, but you may say something else
   more specific to your app).
2. For this notification, provide a `PendingIntent` that starts your activity. As part of the extras for this PendingIntent, *pass the PendingIntent provided by `ConnectionResult.getResolution()`*. PendingIntents are parcelable so this shouldn't pose a problem.
3. In `onCreate()` for this Activity, obtain the *original* `PendingIntent` from the extras, then call `startIntentSenderForResult()` with it. This will automatically redirect the user to wherever Google Play Services needed him to go (possibly log-in?)
4. Then, in `onActivityResult()`, finish the activity, having first notified your service (via an Intent) that the problem is resolved (or not). The transient activity will have been invisible to the user.

I admit this solution is theoretical, but it should work.

Comment: I'm working on another issue so I didn't check it. But I think it's a good solution. Thanks!